# Firebase SMS Verification on iOS - 'Token Mismatch'

Tags: swift, xcode, sms, firebase-authentication, token

When attempting to beta test my application with some external users, none of them could properly enter the app using the phone number sms verification. The developers could all use the application when built directly from Xcode, but anyone who installed via a link could not use it.

Each user attempting to sign in / sign up would get an error readout of `Token Mismatch` - with no other info.

I have a valid production APNS certificate, why is this not working??

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Steps I took to solve the problem:

1. Ensure I had both a valid `development` and `production` APNS
   certificate uploaded to the Firebase Dashboard, under 'Project
   Settings' > 'Cloud Messaging'

[image: dashboardcertificates]

2. In Xcode, in the `<my app>`.entitlements file, make sure the **APS
   Environment** value is set to either 'development' or 'production',
   depending on your testing situation.

[image: entitlements]

3. Finally (this is what I was missing), check inside your
   `AppDelegate.swift` and inside the method for
   `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, change the value
   from `.sandbox` to `.prod`, ***or*** to `.unknown` to let the app
   bundle determine which token type to use, based on your provisioning profile.

[image]

Comment: A well-detailed, well-formatted answer. What a rarity. Keep going!

Comment: I'm having this issue and none of the following have helped me. Any idea what could still be wrong?

Comment: Its not working in iOS 16 Simulator but works fine in Real iPhone.

Answer (score 3):

Step 1:
import Firebase

2.
Add the following to your AppDelegate:-

```
override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    firebaseAuth.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenType.unknown)

}

override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let firebaseAuth = Auth.auth()
    if (firebaseAuth.canHandleNotification(userInfo)){
        print(userInfo)
        return
    }
}
```

At least this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I had `type:FIRAuthAPNSTokenTypeSandbox` in `AppDelegate.m`

Setting it to `type:FIRAuthAPNSTokenTypeProd` resolved the issue.